# How to execute OS commands from oracle apex(web)

Tags: oracle, cloud, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, apex-code

I want to run an export command for my local database from oracle apex. Is there any way of doing that or running the OS commands from oracle Apex. Thanks.

Comment: being able to impact the underlying OS from your web/mid tier could be potentially VERY VERY bad. However, we have built a database maangement REST API that includes an end point for kicking off data pump exports - so you could take advantage of that

Comment: how do i find this API .?

Comment: Full story and example here https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/05/data-pump-via-ords/